# How can I tell what processes are running at shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, reboot

I'm having a problem where it takes ages to shutdown or reboot my computer. Shutdown -h puts it down right away, but otherwise it takes about 5 minutes to shutdown. Booting up is very quick.

How can I tell what is causing this delay? There is nothing in /var/crash

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to run `top` in one terminal while executing `shutdown` in another? That may give you an idea of what are the last processes to terminate.

Comment: I tried doing this but the top process gets killed so it didn't realy work for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can check log file which were stored at /var/log location there you can find all the log related to your system.

or simply try

```
last -x shutdown
```